# Does destroying delete still require destructor being accessible?

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator, c++20

C++20 introduces the concept of a "destroying operator delete", [as described below](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete):

> delete-expressions does not execute the destructor for *p before placing a call to operator delete

So, given the following `struct S`:

```
struct S {
    void operator delete(S* p, std::destroying_delete_t);

private:
    ~S();
};
```

I'd expect the `delete` below to not insert a call to destructor but just call destroying operator delete we provided

```
delete new S;
```

However, GCC/Clang/MSVC behave differently: [DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/fW4KEW)

Only GCC doesn't try to access `~S()`, others still require `~S()` being accessible.

Which one is correct?

Comment: C++20 implementations are not yet complete, so you should check what your compilers claim to support before trying to rely on it.

Comment: @NicolBolas At least cppreference says these compilers all support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gcc is correct: `~S()` need not be accessible.

From [[expr.delete]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#6):

> If the value of the operand of the *delete-expression* is not a null pointer value and the selected deallocation function (see below) is not a destroying operator delete, the *delete-expression* will invoke the destructor (if any) for the object or the elements of the array being deleted.

It's only in the case of *not* destroying delete that the destructor is invoked. Indeed, that's the whole point of destroying delete - to give the class author control of how/when to invoke the destructor. As such, there is no requirement that the destructor be accessible - it's not up to the language to invoke it, it's up to the user.

Comment: I've also seen the sentence, but I'm not sure if it's enough to judge that the standard doesn't require the accessibility to destructor. Indeed, if you make `~S()` public, Clang/MSVC won't invoke the destructor, so aren't they technically conforming?

Comment: @Jamboree This is where we get `delete p;` having to invoke a destructor, there's no other place where that would happen. The language doesn't typically require functions to be accessible even if not invoked. This is definitely a clang bug, I submitted [47474](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47474).

Comment: [expr.delete]p12: "Access and ambiguity control are done for both the deallocation function and the destructor (11.4.7, 11.12)."